# automatic insert into Mysql with C API

Tags: php, mysql, c

I want to simulate the updating process's for my mysql table 
I want to insert every one second a data into mysql table in autaumatic way

the idea is to write a small loop with C API that support sql request (or any other languages)
and execute this loop to insert data to mysql 
I read many topics here or in others forum but I need help to find how to implement the constraint of time ( every one second ).

Answer (score 2):

Most languages have a sleep() function. In the loop sleep() for one second.
PHP: [Sleep()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)
C: [Sleep()](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/111229-how-use-sleep-function.html)

Comment: thanks jim very good news for me !
but for the case of php how I start insert my data, that means my php script should be independent of my system so how to trigger the execution of my loop ?!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, this is a standard load testing methodology:

```
 while (not done)
 {
      sleep (1);
      mysql.query("insert into table values (blah, blah, blah)");
 }
```

Probably you would want to run several instances of this program, and probably refine the use of `sleep()` to use greater precision based on how long the query took.

Comment: yes that's right
I have many data to add, but I want to trigger the program just one time 
Thanks for your helpful post